# Comparing two SDL_Rect types

Tags: c++, sdl

Inside my SDL c++ program, I am trying to compare two SDL_Rects but the '==' operator gives me error

I have defined a newRects array of SDL_Rect types to display a grid of rectangles and initialized it. It works fine

> SDL_Rect newRects[Max_Rows][Max_Columns];

Now I want to see if in my grid of rectangles, if there is a black rectangle so I define the following function. It returns the matched rect of SDL_Rect type.

```
SDL_Rect BlackRect(){
     for(int i = 0; i < Max_Rows ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Max_Columns; j++){
            if(Colors[i][j] == black)
                return newRects[i][j];
        }
     }
}
```

Now if I use compare the two rects it throws me an error, something like this

```
SDL_Rect temp = BlackRect();
if(temp == newRects[0][1])
```

It does not let me compare. I looked into the SDL_Rect class reference and they have a operator== to compare to rects but it does not work here. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you were reading the wrong reference. SDL is a C library and it doesn't contain any classes or operators. Despite this in your C++ program you can write a global compare operator somewhere in a global header files of yours after including the SDL headers:

```
inline bool operator==(const SDL_Rect& a, const SDL_Rect& b)
{
    return a.x==b.x && a.y==b.y && a.w==b.w && a.h==b.h;
}
```

Note that I haven't used SDL a lot and I used it as a pure C library. Maybe someone has already written a C++ wrapper around it that contains helper operators like the one I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this function from SDL to compare 2 rects if you don't want to do it with the operator as stated in the previous answer:

SDL_bool SDL_RectEquals(const SDL_Rect* a, const SDL_Rect* b);
https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RectEquals?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryRect%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29

You would do: if(SDL_RectEquals(temp, newRects[0][1])) ...